# Convert to time in Golang from milliseconds

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I have a some json data where there is a field called **lastModifed** contains time in millis. I wanted to convert this data into a struct type with json.UnMarshaller. I have mapped the field with json filed. But the conversion seems not working.

IE :

My Json looks like this:

```
{
   "name" : "hello",
   "lastModified" : 1438167001716
}
```

and struct Looks like

```
type Model struct {
    Name         string    `json:"name"`
    Lastmodified time.Time `json:"lastModified"`
}
```

looks not converting the time properly. how can i get the time from those millis??

NB: The millis of lastModifiedTime are getting from java `System.currentTimeMillis();`

Comment: The question has lots of tangential content.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

In golang `time.Time` marshals to JSON using [RFC3339](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt), string representation. So you need to unmarshal your json using `int64` instead of `time.Time` and convert after it by yourself:

```
type Model struct {
    Name   string `json:"name"`
    Millis int64  `json:"lastModified"`
}

func (m Model) Lastmodified() time.Time {
    return time.Unix(0, m.Millis * int64(time.Millisecond))
}
```

<kbd>[Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Kxireu3Np8)</kbd>

Also you can use special wrapper above `time.Time` and override UnmarshalJSON there:

```
type Model struct {
    Name         string   `json:"name"`
    Lastmodified javaTime `json:"lastModified"`
}

type javaTime time.Time

func (j *javaTime) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    millis, err := strconv.ParseInt(string(data), 10, 64)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    *j = javaTime(time.Unix(0, millis * int64(time.Millisecond)))
    return nil
}
```

<kbd>[Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/-xARWUapGV)</kbd>

Comment: N.B. this has an implicit validity restriction to the years 1678 to 2261 CE. That's fine for most cases but should at least be noted, as the less readable solution does not have such a restriction.

Comment: I've got 3000 year and got bug.

Answer (score 19):

You can use the `UnixMilli` method in `time`:

```golang
myTime := time.UnixMilli(myMilliseconds)
```

Reference: https://pkg.go.dev/time#UnixMilli

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
func ParseMilliTimestamp(tm int64) time.Time {
    sec := tm / 1000
    msec := tm % 1000
    return time.Unix(sec, msec*int64(time.Millisecond))
}
```